# Would WiFi work at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, technology

A friend and I recently found this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrons.jpg, the important parts shown below.

It's about an IT-Guy who works at Hogwarts to install WiFi and stuff. But WiFi and computers require electricity. Would it be possible to install a power supply at Hogwarts, since it is invisible for muggles? Would electric devices even work? (We know they at the "current state" wouldn't

Also see [How can electricity not work at Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33963/how-can-electricity-not-work-at-hogwarts), but maybe that could be changed)

One of the posts says, he found a fully functional server room, aka the room of requirement. If he sets up the WiFi routers in there, what's gonna happen to all the PC stuff when he leaves/the room disappears? Would the signal vanish right after he leaves the room or would it, like in the post, hold on until the room takes on another form?

---

Screenshot from the link:

[image]

Comment: This is probably not a productive question, but I'm not an expert in this canon.

Comment: i think this is a great question, its a funny article that alot of people are reading this last week.

Comment: For those wondering, this is originally from [The Setup Wizard](http://thesetupwizard.tumblr.com/tagged/setupwizard/chrono).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: The whole answer assumes that it is possible to make Wi-fi routers work in a magical environment where "electricity, and computers and radar, and all those things – they all go haywire". This might be possible by using EMP shielded equipments (see Damon's comment to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6306/60559).

I think the signal would not vanish immediately.

One of the forms in which the Room of Requirements can appear is the Room of Hidden Things. If you enter the RoR thinking "I need a place to hide something/keep something safe", the RoR will appear as the Room of Hidden Things, which by default contains everything that has been hidden there **unless you close the loopholes** (see [Why does the Room of Requirement use the same hiding chamber for everything?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55625/why-does-the-room-of-requirement-use-the-same-hiding-chamber-for-everything)).

Now, Wi-Fi often cannot penetrate thick stone walls, so setting up wireless routers and so on in the Room would probably not be a good idea. However, this seems to be a non-issue:

> inside was a fully functional server room. Delighted, I found the information for the wifi running out of its routers and took a trip around the castle to test the signal strength

If Wi-Fi can indeed penetrate such a thick stone door, the signal would not vanish since the object that is emanating the signal is always there, in the Room of Hidden Things.

Conclusion: under the assumptions made by the guy quoted by the OP, i.e. if 1) electronics could work in Hogwarts, at least under certain conditions, and 2) Wi-fi propagation through a stone wall was not a problem, I think that the signal would not vanish.

Answer (score 7):

No, and the answer has nothing to do with magic. [Wifi is blocked by stone walls](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/m/article/0,,1094325,00.html) , and of course Hogwarts is all about thick stone walls. Getting good signal everywhere in the castle would be next to impossible!

Comment: just run lan through the school and set up hotspots in ever classroom/hallway. it would take work  but you could have reliable single practicly everywhere.

Comment: It would take a LOT of work because pulling cable through stonewalls is really hard too :)

Comment: thats when you just run cables on the ceiling using adhesives, or since were in a magical castle, perhaps use magic to lay the lines, they already have plumbing perhaps we could run electrical and lan next to the plumbing haha.

Comment: Every time you try to run a new segment a Basilisk pops out :)

Answer (score 1):

## Electricity does not function properly in Hogwarts as there is "too much magic in the air".

> “All those substitutes for magic Muggles use — electricity, computers, and  radar, and all those  things — they all  go haywire around  Hogwarts, **there’s too much  magic in the air**.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire - Chapter 28*)</sub>
>
> SO... as Colin's **batteries can't work in Hogwarts**, clearly his camera is running off the magical atmosphere and he is then developing his photographs in the magical potion that causes the figures therein to move.
>   <sub>(*[old jkrowling.com - faq - Why did Colin Creevey's camera work etc?](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430145124/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=81)*)</sub>

It has been speculated that this is because the high level of magical concentration found at Hogwarts gives off electromagnetic interference. If that is true, then using a Faraday cage would probably help.

## Also, wizards have an aversion to muggle technology.

> There is another  reason  for  most  wizards'  avoidance  of  Muggle  devices,  and  that  is  cultural.  The magical  community  prides  itself  on  the  fact  that  it  does not  need  the  many  (admittedly ingenious)  devices that  Muggles have created  to  enable them  to  do  what  can  be  so  easily  done by  magic.  To  fill  one's  house  with tumble  dryers  and  telephones  would be  seen as  an  admission of  magical  inadequacy.
>   <sub>(*[Pottermore - Technology](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/technology)*)</sub>

## As others have pointed out, wifi fails at thick stone walls

Lastly, it should be noted that the blog in question fails to make sense on at least one other major point. The author is a muggle, which would raise all kinds of problems of how he would even get into Hogwarts and how the extremely prejudice magic community would allow it.

Comment: There's a good chance an enterprising wizard might find a magical way to shield anything that goes haywire when exposed to magic.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I don't think that adding more magic to the equation will make electricity any better. But I did add a bit about Faraday Cages.